# Angular.js directive two way binding with loaded data

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a directive that load data from some place else.

Here is my directive:

```
(function() {
    var module = angular.module('HomeModule', ['StorageService']);
    module.directive("home", ['storage',
        function(storage) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                templateUrl: "modules/home/directives/home-directive.html",
                controllerAs: "mediaCtrl",
                controller: function() {
                    var ctrl = this;
                    ctrl.medias = [];
                    storage.get_all(function(items) {
                        var tmp = [];
                        for (id in items) {
                            tmp.push(items[id]);
                        }
                        ctrl.medias = tmp;
                    });

                    // setTimeout(function() {
                    //     ctrl.medias = [{name: "test"}];
                    // }, 3000);
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
})();
```

And my template:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search.name" placeholder="filter medias..." />
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="media in mediaCtrl.medias | filter:search" >
        {{media.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I do not understand is that as soon as I enter something in the filter it updates and then show the data. I even tried to do it with a `setTimeout` just to see if the problem was my custom service but no.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You *don't* want it to update and show the data?

Comment: No the problem is when the data come back it is not updated.

Comment: What does `get_all` look like?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/J0hFgN3R but I don't think that is the problem cause I tried with the setTimeout also (in comment).

Comment: Why don't you try using angular's $timeout funtion? It's the same as setTimeout, except it wraps it in a $scope.apply()

Comment: setTimeout was just for the test my real problem is that when the data come back from my service (or the setTimeout) my html template does not get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your data update function in a $scope.$apply() call, like so:

```
storage.get_all(function(items) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        var tmp = [];
        for (id in items) {
            tmp.push(items[id]);
        }
        ctrl.medias = tmp;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working but I do not understand why? (sorry I am new to angular)

Comment: Check out this very nice article about it: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html